# jquery ui count sortable elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What is the easiest way to count of ui sortable elements?

```
<ul id="sortableList">
  <li class="nosort"></li>
  <li>item 1<li>
  <li>item 2<li>
  <li class="nosort"></li>
  <li>item 3<li>
</ul>
```

Since i have already performed DOM elemens selection
(>:not(.nosort)) in options of sortable function

```
$("#sortableList").sortable({
    items: ">:not(.nosort)"
```

may i use ui.item somehow to count?

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($('#sortableList li').not('.nosort').length);
```

alerts count of `li` elements in `#sortableList` without a class of `.nosort`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use .length since jQuery returns an array with selected items:

```
$('#sortableList li:not(.nosort)').length
```